# Visual studio полностью пересобирает проект при изменении его структуры

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

Проект находится в режиме "только чтение", так что файлы добавляются следующим образом:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="$(SolutionDir)\impl\**\*.c*" />
    <ClInclude Include="$(SolutionDir)\impl\**\*.h*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Все манипуляции с файлами проводятся вне студии. Для обновления данных проект выгружается и загружается вновь.
При добавлении/удалении/переименовании файла студия полностью пересобирает проект, даже если этот файл был пуст.

Это можно как-нибудь побороть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне такое поведение представляется вполне логичным.

Comment: Потому что скорее всего, то что вы там указали собирается в один объектный файл, вместо кучи маленьких. Которые можно потом по отдельности собирать.